# PHP - Insert line break in email post

Tags: php

I've tried many tests to make this work but can't seem to figure this one out!

A PHP code is called before it sends an email, it checks if placeholders have values in them, then adds them in email. Results I get are all on same line with no line breaks.

Can someone please tell me how to insert a line break in the code?

I've tried the linebreak `br` with single quotes and double in many places in the code, nothing is working. I've tried the echo code, I get errors.

Each placeholder starts with the IF statement and must end with the value}'; for each one. Where and how can I insert the line break between the IF and value}';  for each?

Thanks a million!

Results come out like this scapbooking20dancing35

instead of: 
scapbooking
20
dancing
35

if you guys had to put a line break in this code, how does it go? cheers if($_POST['form']['age'] != '') $modAdminEmailText .= '{age:caption}: {age:value}';

---

```
/* Retrieve the admin email text */

$modAdminEmailText = $form->AdminEmailText;

/*Checks if the field has a value and if so, add it to the Email Text*/
if($_POST['form']['hobby'] != '')
  $modAdminEmailText .= '{hobby:caption}: {hobby:value}';

if($_POST['form']['age'] != '')
  $modAdminEmailText .= '{age:caption}: {age:value}';

/*After the field placeholders are added we will need to replace them with the actual submitted values.*/

$adminEmail['text'] = $modAdminEmailText;
$adminEmail['text'] = str_replace($placeholders, $values, $adminEmail['text']);
```

Comment: could you please add some referance how did you give it a try

Comment: What the values of $placeholders and $values variables?

Comment: Results come out like this

scapbooking20dancing35

instead of:
scapbooking
20
dancing
35

if you guys had to put a line break in this code, how does it go?
cheers

if($_POST['form']['age'] != '')
$modAdminEmailText .= '{age:caption}: {age:value}';

Comment: Use `<br>` in case of html mails and if you send text mails you just need to add `\r\n` (Needs to be between " " instead of ' '). I'm not sure why you can't sleep beacuse of this little issue^^

Answer (score 0):

been there, done that. Here's what I think is going on.

> I've tried the linebreak br ... with single quotes and double.. in many many places in the code, nothing is working.. I've tried the echo code, I get errors, 2 days now no sleep :(

using `<br>` in your code will only work if you write the e-mail as HTML. Check the documentation for the e-mail library you use to see how you do that.

Now in stead of using `<br>` you may want to use the `\n` or `\r\n` symbol. Beware, that if you use that, then you must enclose your string with double quotes: `$somevar."\n"`

Alternatively try to use `PHP_EOL` like this: `$somevar. PHP_EOL`

I'm not sure how these two methods behave when using string interpolation, but it's worth a try.

Comment: like this give me an error :    if($_POST['form']['lundi1plat'] != '')
      $modUserEmailText .= '{lundi1plat:caption} : {lundi1plat:value}'"\r\n";

Comment: What error exactly?; my guess is you've forgotten the concatenation operator. Change: `{lundi1plat:value}'"\r\n";` to: {lundi1plat:value}'."\r\n";

Comment: also, something else entirely and something I learned the hard way. Your current `if` statement works just fine, the PHP script will do the thing on the next line. Imagine you need to update your script and want it to do two things for that one if-statement.... you'll notice then, that the if-statement doesn't affect the second line. To make it more readable and avoid that confusion, consider wrapping the if-blocks in brackets: `if (something == True){do this; and this too;}`

Comment: thank captain for taking the time :)
this one ...value}'."\r\n";   gives me the error : syntax error, unexpected ','

Comment: Are you sure the error is related to that line? It says it encountered a comma `,` where there shouldn't be one.